# How to make multiline label on macOS by NSTextField?

Tags: label

I can change label to multiline on IB, by setting `Line Break Mode` to `Character Wrap`, and the layout will auto change:

[image: IB]

---

But when I set it in code, there is still only one line:

```
self.label.maximumNumberOfLines = 5;
self.label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

How to change it by code？